# Angular setting HTTP request origin as null

Tags: angular, cors

For a while, I was trying to to get my local angular build to serve with HTTPS (to learn, and to be sure I wasn't going to run into any SSL issues with the final app). However, after no success, I went back to using `ng serve`, however, all my AJAX requests are failing now. I run a local VM serving a Slim API, and have CORS setup. However, I started seeing the following error:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://gamersplane.local' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Looking at the call in the network tab, I see that the origin header is indeed null, and looking through my code, I don't mess with the origin header (not sure if you can?). I do set an `Authorization` header, but that's it? Here's my API service:

```
private addToken(headers: HttpHeaders) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
        headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    }
    return headers;
}

private constructParams(data?: Object) {
    // Object.keys(data).reduce((params, key) => params.set(key, data[key]), new HttpParams());
    let params = new HttpParams();
    for (let key in data) {
        if (typeof data[key] !== 'object') {
            params = params.set(key, data[key]);
        } else {
            for (let oKey in data[key]) {
                params = params.set(key + '[' + oKey + ']', data[key][oKey]);
            }
        }
    }

    return params;
}


get<T = any>(path: string, data?: Object): Observable<T> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = this.addToken(headers);
    return this.http
        .get<T>(environment.apiDomain + path, {
            headers: headers,
            params: this.constructParams(data)
        });
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: This is unrelated to Angular. The server needs to response with the expected headers, then the browser will make the requests (otherwise refuse).

Comment: How is the request origin being set to null not Angular related? That's not controlled by the CORS pre-flight response?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Angular issue (I think): you have to **allow all origins to access your backend**. Just set the origin header to `*`.

You can also create a proxy for your calls :

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://1.2.3.4:5/",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Fiddle around with the settings, you'ff figure it out.

When you serve,

```
$ ng serve --proxy-conf ./proxy.conf.json
```

With a proxy, your server (ng serve) will make the request, instead of the backend, thus eliminating the need to comply with cross origin constraints.

now, your urls in your services won't be

```
let url = 'http://1.2.3.4:5/api/'
```

But just

```
let url = '/api/'
```

And the proxy will handle this for you.

Comment: I'll check out proxy. But isn't the origin value determined by the system making the request, in this case, Angular?

Comment: Yes, the Header origin is sent by the client. But it's up to the server to decide whether or not to accpet it ! if you accept all incoming requests, you won't have to bother anymore (although you just do it for local testing, obviously)

Comment: I know I can just set it to accept all origins, but if Angular is setting the origin to null in dev, what's to say it won't do it in prod? And as you mentioned, in prod, I won't be allowing all origins.

Comment: It sets its origin to null because you're on a VM. But ultimately, your users won't be on a VM, and if they do, they won't use a local server like you do ! You can test it in production mode, but I think you should be good (I faced this issue last year, and in production mode I never encountered any issue).

Comment: Why would Angular, not on the VM, be setting the origin to null because my API is on a VM? And even if angular was on a VM, why would it be setting it to null?

Comment: Oh Angular isn't on a VM ? My bad then, sorry ! And I'm telling you that because I faced this issue : I was working on a VM and my Angular was messing up my headers. So I migrated back to Windows and everything worked. I can't explain why, I just draw conclusions here. But it is indeed strange that you have a null origin. Do you have a Do not track plugin in your browser ? What happens when you make http calls from postman ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Chrome has a bug when a server responses with a 302 redirect, when it makes the new request, it sets the `Origin` header to null.In my case, my API was responding with a 307, so the second, redirected request was being set to null. Correcting the 307 fixed it (though this seems like a weird issue...)

Comment: I observe this same behavior `Origin` = `null` in Firefox also.